# Need to open an excel file manually in the middle of a macro

Tags: vba, excel

First time posting so please be kind.

From a template file, I am running a macro to create a new folder with a copy of the template file in it. I then rename it and update it. At one point, I need to manually download a file from a website and open it and then start another macro to finish the update.

I initially tried to do that from one unique macro but I got issues as the macro would keep running before the excel file had time to open.

I have now split my macro in 2. At the end of the 1st macro, I call a userform with instructions and a continue button. The idea is that I would download the file while the userform is opened and click on "continue" when the file is opened.

For some reason, the file does not open at all. It seems like either the userform or the macro stops the file from opening. However, If I run it using the debug function, It works fine...

```
Public strSN As String, strPart As String, strPath As String


Sub create_new()


' Create Folder if it doesn't exist
'Dim strSN As String, strPart As String, strPath As String

'strSN = SerialNumber.Value
'strPart = PartNumber.Value
'strPath = "M:\Quality\QUALITY ASSURANCE\DOC\Rental Folder\Scanned MRB's\"

' close userform
welcomeform.Hide

'set Microsoft scription runtime reference to allow creation of folder macro

On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGUID "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-    00A0C9054228}", 1, 0
On Error GoTo 0

If Not FolderExists(strSN) Then
'Serial Number folder doesn't exist, so create full path
FolderCreate strPath & strSN

End If

' Create new file in new folder

On Error Resume Next

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strPath & strSN & "\" & strPart & " " & strSN & " " & "SNR.xlsm"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Copy error: " & strPath & "TEMPLATE SNR.xlsm"
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' open new file without showing it or opening macros

Application.EnableEvents = False   'disable Events
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & strSN & "\" & strPart & " " & strSN & " " & "SNR.xlsm"
Application.EnableEvents = True    'enable Events

' Modify serial number and part number in traceability summary form

Sheets("Traceability Summary Form").Activate
Sheets("Traceability Summary Form").Unprotect
Range("A7").Value = strSN
Range("C7").Value = strPart

' update file with ITP

Call Download_itp

End Sub

Sub Download_itp()

downloaditp.Show

End Sub
```

In the download_itp userform:

```
Sub continue_Click()

Call update_traceable_items

End Sub
```

Then the 2nd macro starts with code:

```
Sub update_traceable_items()
'
' Macro to update the SNR tab with the traceable items from the ITP
'

downloaditp.Hide


' copy ITP in file

Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
ActiveSheet.Name = "ITP"
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Workbooks(strPart & " " & strSN & " " & "SNR.xlsm").Sheets("SNR template")
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Try `application.wait` instead of userform?

Comment: Do you *have* to manually download the file? It's possible (for most files I believe) to have VBA download file X to folder Y.

Comment: @findwindow, I tried 'application.wait' before and it did not work.

Comment: Oh ok ^_^ What about Batman's suggestion?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes I have to manually download the file as it is not always  in the same location and it is through a company specific application.

Comment: I can't see any suggestion from Batman, Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not following what's happening with this code. Where are you "opening" the downloaded file?

Comment: Just a hunch, but try `downloaditp.Show vbModeless`.

Comment: @David Zemens I need to manually open the file, so I call for userform download_itp in between 2 macros to give me the time to do the download and open manually.

Comment: Haha!! Eureca! @David Zemens you are genius! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserForm is being displayed modally, which probably prevents you from "opening" the recently downloaded file. When UserForm is displayed modally, the user is prevented from "interacting" with any part of Excel Application that is not the UserForm itself -- so you can't select cells or worksheets, you can't open files or close files, etc.

This is the default behavior for UserForms, but fortunately there is an optional parameter for the `.Show` method which allows you to display the form "modelessly":

```
downloaditp.Show vbModeless
```

This allows you to interact with the Excel Application while the form is open.

**Note:** If the file is on a shared network location, you can probably handle this better by using a `FileDialog` object to allow you to "browse" to the location of the file, and open it, all within the scope of your main procedure, like:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim NewWorkbook as Workbook
        Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(0))
    End If
End With
```

Comment: What is `downloaditp`? The userform name?  Where does `downloaditp` get declared? (I'm not that familiar with userforms, so it may be a simple answer I'm just missing).

Comment: @BruceWayne I assumed that is the userform name, since OP uses it with the `.Show` method (of UserForm object).  It wouldn't be declared, it's built in the VBE designer and there you can set it's `.Name` property.